# Inline Jquery Timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trent Richardson's great [Jquery Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) plugin instead of the Jquery UI datepicker, but I can't seem to display the datetimepicker or timepicker inline, like you can with the [datepicker in Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline).

This should be all the code that's needed, at least it's how it works with the Jquery UI datepicker:

```
<div class="timepicker"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        ampm: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using the datepicker in that same way would result in an inline calendar that always appears, no need to click an input field.

**How can I display an inline time picker using datetimepicker or another Jquery plugin?**

Comment: Ben, saw this over on github about the timepicker inline:  https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/254  So maybe it's fixed in the dev branch.

Comment: @itsmatt should have checked the issues; yep, the dev version has fixed the inline feature. Thanks a bunch, post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @BenBrocka - You're welcome.  Glad it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/254) and it's in fact fixed in the latest [dev branch](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/tree/dev) for Timepicker. Using the dev branch the inline feature works and I've had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call timepicker from an input text element not a div element.

```
<input type="text" name="time" class="timepicker"/>
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbT35/)

Comment: Calling it from a div is how you get the inline picker, at least for datepicker. The documentation said it supports all options of the original date picker

Answer (score 0):

this is from working code for  static  jquery datetimepicker view :

```
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        lang:'uz',
        // disabled: true,
        format:'d.m.Y H:i',
        // 
    });
```

and in html:

```
<div id="datetimepicker"></div>
```